# Is there another way to exit my program entirely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Is there another way of doing this? I have added "sys.exit()" if a user pressed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button on his/her keyboard and somehow it does not exit my program completely, only the "on_press" function is still active. I tried it in my other code and it works, but here it doesn't. I even added a "L.stop" to somehow stop the keyboard listener but still won't budge. I added a try/except block to just test it temporarily to see if it really captures the exception, and it did captured it.

```
import sys
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1106, 1080)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")


while True:

    SEARCH_HOTKEY = [
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.Key.shift_l, 
         keyboard.KeyCode(char='i')},
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.Key.shift_l, 
         keyboard.KeyCode(char='I')}
        ]

    SEARCH_2_HOTKEY = [
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.Key.shift_l, 
         keyboard.KeyCode(char='f')},
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.Key.shift_l, 
         keyboard.KeyCode(char='F')}
        ]

    EXIT_KEY = [
        {keyboard.Key.esc}
        ]

    ENTER_KEY = [
        {keyboard.Key.enter}
        ]

    CLOSE_KEY = [
        {keyboard.Key.tab}
        ]
    current = set()
    toaster = ToastNotifier()


     def on_press(key):

        global driver
        if any([key in HOT for HOT in EXIT_KEY]):
           current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in HOT) for HOT in EXIT_KEY):

                driver.quit()
                L.stop()
                print("Exiting...")
                sys.exit() #####This raises the exception, but it doesn't exit 
                      the program


        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in ENTER_KEY]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in HOT) for HOT in ENTER_KEY):

               toaster.show_toast("Hello Fellow User", "It seems that you 
               have not inputted something, please press Shift+I to input")

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in CLOSE_KEY]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in HOT) for HOT in CLOSE_KEY):

                driver.close()

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in SEARCH_HOTKEY]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in HOT) for HOT in SEARCH_HOTKEY):

                L.stop()
                #SOME CODES HERE
                #SOME CODES HERE
                #SOME CODES HERE
                #SOME CODES HERE

    def on_release(key):
        if any([key in HOT for HOT in SEARCH_2_HOTKEY]):
            current.remove(key)

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in SEARCH_HOTKEY]):
            current.remove(key)

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in EXIT_KEY]):
            current.remove(key)

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in ENTER_KEY]):
            current.remove(key)

        elif any([key in HOT for HOT in CLOSE_KEY]):
            current.remove(key)

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press, on_release = on_release) as L:
        L.join()
```

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you might be able to `del listenerClass`

Comment: Try returning False instead of sys.exit(). According to the [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) documentation, `return False` in any of the listener's callbacks should stop the listener.